# Bucle para subplots matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, bucles, matplotlib

Ya hacía tiempo que no pasaba por aquí, pero me gustaría saber si alguien me podría ayudar. Estoy ploteando dos gráficas por cada archivo que tengo en una carpeta. Cada archivo tiene tres columnas A, B y C. La representación es en el subplot izquierdo B en el eje de ordenadas y A en el eje de abcisas mientras que en el subplot derecho C en el eje de ordenadas y A en el eje de abcisas (figura adjunta).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como no puedo adjuntar los archivos pongo una representación mínima de lo que sería cada uno de ellos.

```
A    B     C
1    0     0
2    0.5   -0.5
3    1     -1
4    0.5   -0.5
.    .     . 
.    .     .
```

Tengo un script que lo plotea pero únicamente se hacerlo manualmente uno a uno y tengo que hacerlo para más de 15 archivos. Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce como hacer un bucle para que empiece dibujando el primer par de subplots del archivo número 1, luego del número 2 y así sucesivamente añadiendo los subplots a la misma figura.

Aquí pongo el código:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Data read
data1=np.genfromtxt("01.txt",encoding="utf-8",dtype=None,names=True,delimiter=";")
data4=np.genfromtxt("02.txt",encoding="utf-8",dtype=None,names=True,delimiter=";")
data7=np.genfromtxt("03.txt",encoding="utf-8",dtype=None,names=True,delimiter=";")


# Data for plotting
t1 = data1["A"]
s1 = data1["B"]
r1 = data1["C"]
t4 = data4["A"]
s4 = data4["B"]
r4 = data4["C"]
t7 = data7["A"]
s7 = data7["B"]
r7 = data7["C"]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,2)
axs[2,0].plot(t4, s4)
axs[2,0].set_ylabel('HR08')
axs[2,1].plot(t4, r4, 'tab:orange')
axs[1,0].plot(t1, s1)
axs[1,0].set_ylabel('HR09')
axs[1,1].plot(t1, r1, 'tab:orange')
axs[0,0].plot(t7, s7)
axs[0,0].set_ylabel('HR12')
axs[0,1].plot(t7, r7, 'tab:orange')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```

Muchas gracias y disculpad si incurro en algún error que ya no recuerdo del todo bien las normas para postear.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, unas cuantas dudas ¿los archivos en tu caso real están nombrados exactamente siguiendo ese patrón? Es decir, ¿por ejemplo del 0.1txt al 15.txt sin saltarse ninguno? Por otro lado, los estas graficando en orden inverso, primero el 0.3.txt, luego el 0.2.txt..., pero en la pregunta parece que explicas  que el 0.1.txt debería ser el primero ¿cual sería el orden? Por último, ¿de donde salen las etiquetas del eje y ('HR08', etc))? ¿Siguen algún patrón para poder ir generandolas según el archivo? Por último, quieres todos los subplots juntos, porque serian mas de 15 filas...

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu interés. No saltaría ninguno, serían correlativos. Mi intención es que el último archivo quede arriba y el primero abajo en los subplots, por eso los he puesto en ese orden. Las etiquetas vendrían del nombre del archivo que aunque yo haya posteado aquí una versión básica (01.txt, etc...), los archivos tendrían el siguiente patrón (01HR02eventX.txt, 02HR03eventX.txt, 03HR05eventX.txt, etc...), es decir el número sería correlativo pero el HR__ podría no serlo. No se si he aclarado todas tus dudas. Si se pudiesen plotear en dos ventanas (izqda y dcha), mejor.Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que el nombre de los archivos es de la forma:

```
nnHRii*.txt
```

donde `n` e `i` son dígitos, es decir dos dígitos seguidos de "HR" y dos dígitos más, puedes simplemente listar los archivos con `glob`, ordenarlos en orden inverso según su nombre (dado que empiezan siempre con dos dígitos, el orden lexicográfico nos vale perfectamente) y luego simplemente iterar sobre la lista de archivos e ir generando los subplots.

La etiqueta del eje *y* se puede extraer simplemente mediante un rebanado del nombre.

```
import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


dir_path = pathlib.Path('') # Ruta al directorio de los archivos
files = sorted(dir_path.glob(r'[0-9][0-9]HR[0-9][0-9]*.txt'), reverse=True)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(files), 2)

# Data read
for row, file_path in enumerate(files):
    data = np.genfromtxt(
        file_path,
        encoding="utf-8",
        dtype=None,
        names=True,
        delimiter=";"
    )

    # Data for plotting
    t = data["A"]
    s = data["B"]
    r = data["C"]

    # Extract HR label
    hr = file_path.name[2:6]

    axs[row, 0].plot(t, s)
    axs[row, 0].set_ylabel(hr)
    axs[row, 1].plot(t, r, 'tab:orange')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```